# How to extend sidebar and content to full height even without content

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is a sample of what I got so far. [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/TJ84v/)

In my HTML, I have this :

```
<div id="mainContainer">

    <div id="header">

        <p>header here</p>
            </div>

            <div id="centerRightColumnContainer">

                <div id="centerRightColumnPositioner">

                    <div id="centerColumnContainer">

                        <div id="centerColumn">

                            <p>menu here</p>


                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>  

            </div>

            <div id="sideBarLeft">
                <p>side bar</p>
            </div>                  
</div>
```

In my css i have :

```
    body
    {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    }
#bg
    {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 960px;
    z-index: -1;
    }

body > #bg
    {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    }

#mainContainer
    {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 960px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    }

#header
        {
        background-color: black;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 10px;
        }

#centerRightColumnContainer
    {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    }

#centerRightColumnPositioner
    {
    margin-left: 190px; 
    padding: 0; 
    }

#sideBarLeft
    {
    float: left;
    width: 190px;
    margin-left: -100%;
    padding: 0;
    background-color : maroon;
    }

#centerColumnContainer
    {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background-color : gray;
    }

#centerColumn
    {
    /* margin-right: 260px; */
    padding: 10px;
    }



body
        {
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 13px;
        line-height: 17px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        }

p
        {
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

.clear_both
        {
        clear: both;
        }

#sideBarLeft p
    {
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 170px;
    }


#rightColumnBg > #sideBarLeft
    {
    height: auto;
    }
```

lastly in JS :

```
function resize_bg_div(){
    var var_bg_offset = document.getElementById('header').offsetHeight;
    array_colHeights = new Array( );
    array_colHeights.push( document.getElementById("sideBarLeft").offsetHeight );
    array_colHeights.push( document.getElementById("centerColumn").offsetHeight );
    array_colHeights.push( window.innerHeight - var_bg_offset );
    array_colHeights.sort( function( a, b ){ } );
    document.getElementById('bg').style.height = array_colHeights[0] + "px";
    delete array_colHeights;
        delete var_bg_offset;
}


window.onload = resize_bg_div;
window.onresize = resize_bg_div;
```

Now, I want to set the side bar and the content to maximum height even when it has no text or any content in it.. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `delete array_colHeights; delete var_bg_offset;` why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are ok with jquery than use below code...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var header_height = $('#header').height();
    var content_height = $(window).height() - header_height;
    var container_height = $('#centerRightColumnContainer').height();
    var sidebar_height = $('#sideBarLeft').height();
    if(container_height > sidebar_height)
        var main_height = container_height;
    else
        var main_height = sidebar_height;
    if(content_height > main_height)
        var main_height = content_height;

    $('#centerRightColumnContainer,#sideBarLeft').css('height',main_height);
});
```

Comment: thanks, but see this[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TJ84v/5/)
when i had content on header, it spills to sidebar and content area,because when window minimized, the header area,shrinks or resized.

Comment: thanks ,i change now to auto, but i notice, i dont get the full height of the browser, and sometimes when i refresh browser,the div bg color height changes. and also the text of the header, menu moves. waaaaaaaaaahhh. dont know why.

Comment: sidebar height exceed to my browser height,but thanks. ill be back on you,if i cant make it. thanks sir

Comment: if i had more content of menu, it spills sir. how can i get browser height dynamically? see the menu in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TJ84v/11/)

Comment: `$(document).height();`  to get full page height.

Comment: I have already solved this issue but i think you have not set my latest code... Check this answere...

Answer (score -3):

I would not recommend doing this with JavaScript.

This is a well known problem in web design.
You can use a flex to achieve this:
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3yQDH/12/)

The wrapper does the magic:

```
#wrapper { display: flex; }
```

Flexbox is not supported by old browsers. Read [this article](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: this doesn't answer my question. when i remove the text in content `div` the wrapper shrinks.

Comment: The wrapper does not shrink. The content shrinks. Everything is red, right? Give me one second, this is a tricky one.

Comment: oh yes.. sorry for that. alright. thanks in advance!

Comment: I updated my answer. This should give you an idea. It works in all modern browsers. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your effort,but this doesn't answer my question again. if i remove the text from sidebar and content, no div or background will show. My wanted result, is that i want to see the divs background color,as an evident that div extends to bottom even without content.

Comment: You mean like this? Updated the post again. Now, the divs are always visible with their background color.

Comment: close to, but if you will minimize the window of your code,the sidebar,header and content will shrink,and thats not what i want, i want  the content to just stay put(not shrink or resize when browser minimized),and only scrolls will show.see my posted fiddle before,when i minimized,content doesnt move, just scroll.(you can see better the scroll if it has a content,but again, i want the full height even w/o content)

Comment: Now, you are always able to see the content. Scrollbar is also there. This should be the final answer. If not, I am gonna eat my pants.

Comment: your close to eat your pants sir.haha there are no scroll at y-axis, i need both scroll, x and y. and this should work atleast for IE7, and other browser,of course. thanks

Comment: There is a scroll in the y-axis if the text is bigger than the screen. It works on the new browser versions. Everyone who is still using IE7 should be punched in the throat.