# Background color/image of div expand the whole page, but content stays in wrapper

Tags: html, css

This seems so trivial, but how do I make the background color or image of a div span the whole window, but keep the content in a wrapper or set width? Almost like a footer, or nav.

Like on this page in the footer, the gray and the  lack parts go the whole across the page but any type is still in a set width that matches the rest of the page. Some pages have these in the middle and divide their whole page using this technique.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extend sidebar and content to full height even without content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24239419/how-to-extend-sidebar-and-content-to-full-height-even-without-content)

Comment: Sorry, I'm looking for width, not height

Comment: try to read that,just change code to fit it to width which what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

For a content wrapper, make the wrapper div fixed width and use margin: 0 auto to center it horizontally - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kwebf

```
<style type="text/css">
  body { 
    background: #ff0000; 
  }
  div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
  }
</style>
<body>
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

For fixed width content without a wrapper, put horizontal padding on your body - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hoKdk

```
<style type="text/css">
    body { 
        padding: 0 200px;
        background: #ff0000; 
    }
</style>
<body>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could either wrap each section in an element (A) just to span across the page and prodive the background, and wrap the content in an element (B) to center it in A. like this:

```
<div id="main-wrap">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer-wrap">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<style>
  #main-wrap {
    background:red;
  }
  #footer-wrap {
    background:green;
  }
  .content {
    width:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
  }
</style>
```

or you could use an advanced solution similar to [this one](http://css-tricks.com/full-browser-width-bars/).

it really depends on your design and requirments